# R associative memory doesn't work as expected

Tags: r, memory

I am trying to use associative memory and ddply to add a column to a data frame. For example:

First, I have defined association and a function that uses association to calculate product of two elements of a row (property damage and multiplier) to get actual damage in dollars. Here,"B" means Billion, "m|M" means MIllions, etc.

```
   validMultiplierLetter <- c("B", "h", "H", "k", "K", "m", "M")
    Multiplier <- c(1000000000, 100, 100, 1000, 1000, 1000000, 1000000)
    names(Multiplier) <- validMultiplierLetter
```

The function ploss (property loss) is:

```
ploss <- function(pd,pm) {
  if (pm %in% validMultiplierLetter) pd*Multiplier[pm]
  else 0
  }
```

here is a sample data frame with columns pd (property damage) and pm (multiplier) and ddply code to create a pl (property loss) column, which is a product of property damage and the associated value of multiplier. Invalid multipliers are equivalent to 0 (e.g., "+").

```
tdf <- data.frame(pd = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25), pm = c("B", "m", "K", "+", "h"))

tldf <- ddply(tdf, .(pd, pm), transform, pl = ploss(pd,pm))
```

I get the following output when I execute the code above - you can see that the right multiplier was not used for the rows.

```
> tldf
  pd pm    pl
1  5  B   500
2 10  m 10000
3 15  K 15000
4 20  +     0
5 25  h  2500
```

Strangely though, when you pass constant, the multiplier works correctly. But, when you pass a variable (whose value is same as the constant), for some reason you get an incorrect result.

```
> Multiplier["B"]
    B 
1e+09 
> tdf$pm[1]
[1] B
Levels: + B h K m
> Multiplier[tdf$pm[1]]
  h 
100
```

Any explanation of why this happens and how to fix it is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are subsetting with a factor. You need to do something like: `with(tdf, pd * Multiplier[as.character(pm)] )`, or declare `tdf` like `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` so you don't get a factor to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `tdf$pm` is a factor.  When presented a factor, `[` will use the factor levels rather than the character values:

```
x <- 10:15
names(x) <- LETTERS[1:6]
x
##  A  B  C  D  E  F 
## 10 11 12 13 14 15 
x[c('A','F')]         # Lookup by name
##  A  F 
## 10 15 
x[factor(c('A','F'))] # Lookup by integer
##  A  B 
## 10 11
```

This is fixed by using `as.character` around the factor, so that a character vector is presented to `[`:

```
x[as.character(factor(c('A','F')))]
##  A  F 
## 10 15
```

For your problem, you can coerce to character in the transform function:

```
ddply(tdf, .(pd, pm), transform, pl = ploss(pd,as.character(pm)))
##   pd pm      pl
## 1  5  B 5.0e+09
## 2 10  m 1.0e+07
## 3 15  K 1.5e+04
## 4 20  + 0.0e+00
## 5 25  h 2.5e+03
```

In addition, you could vectorize your `ploss` function in the obvious way and do the job directly with `transform`:

```
ploss <- function(pd,pm) {
  ifelse(pm %in% validMultiplierLetter, pd*Multiplier[pm], 0)
}

transform(tdf, pl=ploss(pd, as.character(pm)))
##   pd pm      pl
## 1  5  B 5.0e+09
## 2 10  m 1.0e+07
## 3 15  K 1.5e+04
## 4 20  + 0.0e+00
## 5 25  h 2.5e+03
```

And of course, the `as.character` coercion could be within the function `ploss`, so it isn't required in the `transform` call:

```
ploss <- function(pd,pm) {
  ifelse(pm %in% validMultiplierLetter, pd*Multiplier[as.character(pm)], 0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your illustration of vectorization followed by transform, as an alternative to ddply, was very helpful. After I used the as.character, running my code with ddply on my large data set took a long time and eventually I was getting "ran out of memory" message. When I used vectorization followed by transform, it ran like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that, if you're using the default R options, `tdf$pm` is a `factor`, not a `character`. You can check this with `class(tdf$pm)`. What's happening here is that `"B"` is really a mask for `2` (following the order in the printout: `Levels: + B h K m`), so `pd` has the value of `2` as far as `[` is concerned, and `Multiplier[2]` is 100 as you've assigned.

When you call `data.frame` (or `read.table`) you need to add the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, or change the corresponding global option with the `options` function.

Comment: Changing the corresponding global option is probably not a good idea. Particularly if you are running other code where the authors have assumed the default values are set.